# Sandboxed Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) is great, but too opinionated. Selectors in its rules are very broad, like `input` or `label`.

Is there a way to sandbox Bootstrap's CSS so that it only applies the rules to elements in a container with *a certain class*?

Right now we had to `replace-regexp` the CSS source to prepend `.bootstrap` to every selector. However, it might break Bootstrap's modal windows and whatnot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a scoped style block that contains an `@import` rule in it. You could even write a small JS to add this to every element that has your desired class.

```
<div class="untouched">
</div>
<div class="bootstrapped">
<style scoped>
    @import url("bootstrap.css");
</style>
</div>
```

The tentative jQuery:

```
$('.bootstrapped').prepend('<style scoped>@import url("bootstrap.css");</style>');
```

I realize `scope` isn't very widely supported, so here's a polyfill: https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin

Comment: Oh, this is so great W3C have thought about it! Does it work in *any* current browser? Anyway, I suppose it's the only right way if Bootstrap isn't changing its attitude.

Comment: @katspaugh No, not really, but maybe someday. Just use the polyfill in the meantime.